# react-native-voice and config-plugin

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am working on a mobile application with React Native with expo, I need to implement a function to record and transcribe what is said into the microphone.
I have tried many solutions but none really work, the only one that seems to come close is @react-native-voice/voice.

I install @react-native-voice/voice:
npm i @react-native-voice/voice

my code:

```js
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { NativeBaseProvider } from "native-base";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import Voice from "@react-native-voice/voice";

const App = () => {
  let [started, setStarted] = useState(false);
  let [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;

    return () => {
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    };
  }, []);

  const startSpeechToText = async () => {
    await Voice.start("en-NZ");
    setStarted(true);
  };

  const stopSpeechToText = async () => {
    await Voice.stop();
    setStarted(false);
  };

  const onSpeechResults = (result) => {
    setResults(result.value);
  };

  const onSpeechError = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  };

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {!started ? (
          <Button title="Start Speech to Text" onPress={startSpeechToText} />
        ) : undefined}
        {started ? (
          <Button title="Stop Speech to Text" onPress={stopSpeechToText} />
        ) : undefined}
        {results.map((result, index) => (
          <Text key={index}>{result}</Text>
        ))}
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
export default App;
```

I start my application and when I press the register button it returns this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Voice.startSpeech')]

I then launch expo doctor it returns:

> Expected package @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.2
> Found invalid:
> @expo/config-plugins@2.0.4

I've never seen this and don't know it, has anyone solved a similar problem yet?
all versions of @react-native-voice/voice have @expo/config-plugins@2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

**This will seem like to much effort** but believe me it is very straight forward, so bare with me:

`react-native-voice` does not work with expo out of the box, you have to use EAS build system to be able use this library.

First install the library

`expo install @react-native-voice/voice expo-dev-client`

Add the plugins value to `app.json`

```
"plugins": [
      [
        "@react-native-voice/voice",
        {
          "microphonePermission": "Allow Voice to App_Name to access the microphone",
          "speechRecognitionPermission": "Allow Voice to App_Name to securely recognize user speech"
        }
      ]
    ],
```

If you don't have eas go ahead and install

`npm install -g eas-cli`

then login to your expo account

`eas login` then `eas build:configure`

Once you `eas.json` file is created, add `simulator:true` value to build>development>ios in the `eas.json` file like so:

```
 "build": {
    "development": {
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
```

Then you can run `eas build -p ios --profile development --local` to create a development build that you can use on your Simulator.

Once this build finishes it will create a `.tar` file on the project root, simply double click on the tar file and drag and drop the exported file into your simulator.

Comment: Hi, I performed as you advised but the problem is not solved.
At the moment it does not allow me to do the build and with expo doctor I always get the problem: 
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.2
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@2.0.4

Answer (score -2):

I run through the same problem on android, we are still waiting to fix this problem

Comment: This is not a useful answer, should be a comment instead